# Displaying a MySQL table with blob images

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I am only starting with PHP and as a part of exercise I wanted to design small website that allows you to upload image and then display all uploaded images

I got the image upload succesfully working and images are stored in database but I cant find the way to display images in table along with other data

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<td>'.mysql_result($result,$i,0).'</td>';
echo '<td>'.mysql_result($result,$i,1).'</td>';
echo '<td>'.mysql_result($result,$i,2).'</td>';
echo '<td>'.mysql_result($result,$i,3).'</td>';
echo '<td>'.base64_encode($result,$i,4).'</td>';
echo '<tr>';
$i++;
```

How to modify the code so the image is displayed?

this is code used to upload image

```
    if (isset($_FILES['photo']))
    {
        @list(, , $imtype, ) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
        // Get image type.
        // We use @ to omit errors

        if ($imtype == 3) // cheking image type
            $ext="png";   // to use it later in HTTP headers
        elseif ($imtype == 2)
            $ext="jpeg";
        elseif ($imtype == 1)
            $ext="gif";
        else
            $msg = 'Error: unknown file format';

        if (!isset($msg)) // If there was no error
        {
            $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
            $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
            // Preparing data to be used in MySQL query

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table}
                            SET ext='$ext', title='$title',
                                data='$data'");
```

This is where I test it [enter link description here](http://k00138899.atspace.eu/photoalbum/photo.php)

I was looking at Stack Overflow examples, but I couldn't find any that has the loop in it with data outputted into a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are starting with PHP, you should start with the right foot :)

- Don't use mysql_* functions, these are deprecated. Instead, use mysqli_* or PDO
- Storing images in the DB is "a bad idea", you better store the files in the file system (a-k.a. the HD) and reference the name to a field in the DB.
- Instead of mysql_fetch_array, try with mysql_fetch_assoc so you can call the fields by name. i.e.: $row['db_field_name'];

About your problem, you will need a extra script to display the stored image. Something like this:

```
<?php
...
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); //Set the correct image type.
echo $row['data'];
exit;
?>
```

And in your display html:

```
...
<img src="yourscript.php?image=XX" ...>
...
```

Hope this help :)